# Objective-C on macOS - get keyDown: for Shift+Tab in NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard

I have an application that processes keystrokes via keyDown.

This works well so far, with the exception of two problems (I'll post/ask the other later).

The problem here is the Shift+Tab combo.  I would like to process it myself, but as explained in the [Mac OS keyboard event doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html), it is used to move the focus forward.

I tried capturing it under

```
-(BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent *)nsevent
{

}
```

where I do get an event for it, returning TRUE or FALSE but it still does not appear in keyDown:

I also know about *selectNextKeyView:* but ideally I am looking for a way to get the system to pass the combination to keyDown: for normal handling (incidentally keyUp: is called correctly for it).

```
-(void)selectNextKeyView:(id)sender
{
    // shift+tabbed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I solved it by intercepting selectNextKeyView and selectPreviousKeyView and forwarding the [NSApp currentEvent] to my keyboard handler (the one that is called on keyDown: for all other keys)

```
-(void)selectNextKeyView:(id)sender
{
    // this is part of the keyboard handling.  Cocoa swallows ctrl+Tab and
    // calls sselectNextKeyView, so we create a matchin key event for the occasion
    NSEvent *nsevent= [NSApp currentEvent];
    [self handleKeyEvent:nsevent isRaw:FALSE isUp:FALSE];
}

-(void)selectPreviousKeyView:(id)sender
{
    // this is part of the keyboard handling.  Cocoa swallows ctrl+shift+Tab and
    // calls selectPreviousKeyView, so we create a matchin key event for the occasion
    NSEvent *nsevent= [NSApp currentEvent];
    [self handleKeyEvent:nsevent isRaw:FALSE isUp:FALSE];
}
```

Comment: This is not ideal because these methods could get called for other reasons, not just Shift+Tab.

Comment: Plus, you should consider using some other key combination since users will be used to using Tab and Shift+Tab to navigate controls, and would be surprised that it doesn't work for your app.